# Conan build mixes release and debug

Tags: c++, conan

I tried to build a simple cmake application under windows. The application has the dependency to gtest, which is installed via conan. The Basic setup of the project is as follows:

conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
gtest/1.11.0

[generators]
cmake_find_package
cmake_paths
cmake
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
project(conan-myapp)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_paths.cmake)
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

enable_testing()
include_directories(${GTest_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(myapp "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(myapp GTest::gtest_main GTest::gtest )
add_test(myapp bin/myapp)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(mytest, testit) {
    EXPECT_TRUE(false);
}
```

I used the following commands to build the application:

```
mkdir build
cd build 
conan install ..
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

But I get the following error message

> gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for
> '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
> [T:\project\build\cocpp19.vcxproj]
>
> gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value
> 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj
> [T:\project\build\cocpp19.vcxproj]
>
> gtest_main.lib(gtest_main.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
> [T:\project\build\cocpp19.vcxproj]
>
> gtest_main.lib(gtest_main.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': > value
> 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj
> [T:\project\build\cocpp19.vcxproj]
>
> LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib
> 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
> [T:\project\build\cocpp19.vcxproj]

Answer (score 2):

As the error message indicates, there is a mix between release and debug builds. The conan installs a release version of gtest. The project is build as debug. To avoid this mixing sprecify the build type, i.e for debug the following command works

```
conan install .. -s build_type=Debug
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
cmake --build .
```

For release you can use

```
conan install .. -s build_type=Release
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cmake --build .
```

Comment: Correct! By default, Conan builds Release, but Cmake builds Debug.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this same issue, and it turns out the culprit was missing settings declaration in my `conanfile.py`:

```
class MyProject(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "arch", "compiler", "build_type"
```

Once I added it, the build type is correctly passed to CMake without needing to specify it manually. It also works with `conan build`.

I'm not sure it's possible to achieve with `conanfile.txt`, but switching to `conanfile.py` is easy:

```
from conans import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake

class MyProject(ConanFile):
    name = "my_project"
    version = "0.1"
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    requires = "gtest/1.11.0"
    generators = "cmake_find_package", "cmake_paths", "cmake"
```